# YOLO not predicting bounding boxes

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api, yolo

I completed YOLO assignment of Deep Learning Specialization in coursera, and It predicted boxes on test.jpg as required in the assignment. But then I downloaded yolo.weights from official darknet website and converted it to .h5 format to process in Keras, and I copied some of my coursera's code like yolo_filter_boxes etc etc. and ran it on my laptop on exact same image test.jpg, but it predicted 0 boxes.

There was one line of code in assignment K.get_session() which didn't made sense to me, and with this I thought maybe on backend coursera had some session going on, in there maybe compiled or fit something like that. I don't know.

I expected to have output cars with their bounded boxes but it didn't happened. Any help regarding this will be really appreciated.

Comment: I think `get_session()` is quite common to keras. You always work in sessions. Either on your CPU or on your GPU if present and by referencing the session, you can move the data to the corresponding devce. So don't worry, you most likely won't move your data to one member of the yola team if you use this code.

Answer (score 0):

The weights from darknet need not correspond to the configuration file i.e, the model architecture might be different. Try checking model input size and also maybe some other method to convert yolo.weights to h5. 
Try this [link](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3).

Comment: Actually I solved this problem. 

I downloaded the yoloVERSION 3 wights but assignment on coursera was on yoloVERSION 2. And there output layer is different from each other.